# Is it possible to call a method twice, first call the real implementation, then mock the results?

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to test that a recursive method properly re-curses. 
The first call should therefore `callRealMethod`. But the second call is just to verify that it was called, and should not actually make the call but rather it should return a stubbed result.

Is there any way to do this in Mockito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [thenCallRealMethod](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenCallRealMethod()), followed by a regular [thenReturn](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn(T)) stub:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class PartialMock {
    String doIt() {
        return "original";
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoIt() {
        PartialMock t = mock(PartialMock.class);
        when(t.doIt())
                .thenCallRealMethod()
                .thenReturn("mocked");

        assertEquals("original", t.doIt());
        assertEquals("mocked", t.doIt());
        assertEquals("mocked", t.doIt());
        verify(t, times(3)).doIt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice! Never thought of that